# I cannot connect FTP to server in Windows 10 to update website

Tags: ftp

Windows 10 will not allow connection to the server with FTP which I need to update a website

Comment: I'm sorry, there isn't enough information here for us to say anything useful. Please [edit] your question with all relevant details.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest the following:

1. Test the ftp from another computer to make sure it is accessible
2. If it is, open command prompt and try telnet [ftp server] 21
3. If this opens a blank screen it is open, if not it will give an error
4. If this works then open the browser and type ftp://[ftp server]

If a pc from outside your office can connect but none of the pc's inside the office the office firewall is blocking ftp.

If other pc's in the office can connect but telnet on your pc gives an error, then your Windows firewall or antivirus is blocking ftp access.